# SEO question, getting info about websites

Tags: api, seo, links

I don't know much about SEO.
I have a csv file with 200,000 links to websites
i want to add another field (or maybe couple of them) to each link in the csv file with page ranking of each link and maybe other interesting metrics and info about the link.

I saw a free API from http://apiwiki.seomoz.org/ i can maybe use to build a simple script, but it's limited to 3 links for second which will roughly take 1100 minutes or 18 hours to run

any other ideas how to get this kind of simple metrics about each link ?

thanks !

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what would you use this information for? Surely you don't have 200,000 competitors and even if you did you wouldn't need to worry about all of them. And if you're building a tool for tracking seo stats why not just build this information dynamically the first time the information is requested and then save it for future reference?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon has opened up the Alexa data as a service http://aws.amazon.com/awis/